# doBy like summaryBy function with chi-square/Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon Test depending on column type

Tags: r

The `doBy` package has a fairly nifty `summaryBy` function that creates a dataframe with descriptive variables divided on variables of interest. I was wondering if there was any way to pad these results with chi-square (for columns that are logical) and Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon (for columns that are numeric).

Comment: Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon would compare two columns. You'll have to explain how this works. If you had `summaryBy(X+C+F+N~A+B,FUN=dotests)` where X is numeric and C is a count and F is ordered categorical while N is nominal (as are A and B), what should happen (i.e. what should that function be doing?)

Comment: You'll also need to explain which chi-squared test you mean